# Selecting Specific Element Within Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am a beginner with jQuery and I'm struggling a little trying to work this out:

So I have something similar to this:

```html
<div class="app">
<div class="app-text"></div>
</div>

<div class="app">
<div class="app-text"></div>
</div>
```

I want to use jquery to change the color of .app-text but when using .app-text it will also change the app-text in the other div (obviously) so how would I go about just changing just the .app-text within the .app div that is being hovered on. The event needs to be triggered when hovering on .app div.

(there will be quite a number of .app divs on the same page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(selector, context)`:

```
$('.app').hover(function(){
   $('.app-text', this).foo()
  }, function(){
   $('.app-text', this).bar()
})
```

Comment: @Tats_innit Hey bro, Thanks `:)`, how are you?

Comment: @Tats_innit haha, me too `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.app').hover(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('.app-text');
    ...
});
```

or, in CSS3 compatible browsers:

```
.app:hover .app-text {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access hovered element with `this`.

Try something like this:

```
$('.app').hover(function(){ //function on hover-in
                  $('.app-text', this).css('color', 'red');
               }, 
               function(){ //function on hover-out
                  $('.app-text', this).css('color', 'black');
               });
```